# Cerrar sesión por inactividad en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

la cuestión es que soy nuevo en Laravel y estoy desarrollando un proyecto, tengo un login implementando, pero me gustaría agregar la funcionalidad de que luego de un tiempo de inactividad se cierra la sesión y me redirija al login.

Agradecería si me pueden dar ideas de cómo hacerlo o dónde puedo ver para poder implementar eso.

Answer (score 0):

- En tu config/auth.php
- En el valor de tu key : 'password_timeout' => 10800, es el tiempo definido es segundos para una session destruirse. Puedes cambiarlo a como se ajuste tu necesidad.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero lo intenté y no me redirige al login, se queda en la vista luego de haber iniciado sesión. ¿Sabes por qué?

Answer (score 0):

Si éstas usando la autenticación de laravel por defecto. Ve a la carpeta **Controller** luego a la carpeta **Auth**, ingresa al controlador **AutenticatedSessionController** en la funcion create() coloca

```
return view('auth.login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Para destruir una sesion por inactividad debes ir a tu **archivo de configuracion .env** y establecer la clave `SESSION_LIFETIME=120` a un valor que desees, `SESSION_LIFETIME=12` para 12 minutos por ejemplo.

La otra forma es editando directamente
config/session y en el parametro lifetime establecer el valor deseado
`'lifetime'=>12` por ejemplo para 12 minutos

*Nota. El param 'password_timeout' en **config/auth.php** destruye cualquier sesion, incluyendo las activas, por tanto no es la respuesta a tu pregunta.*